# Result is way to small binomial distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

> A minibus has 9 passenger seats. The probability of a seat being
>   occupied is estimated to be 0.63. Calculate the probability that on a
>   typical run:

P(0 seats being occupied)
$$
{}_9C_0*.63^0*(1-.63)9^{-0}
$$
This give me the answer to no seats being taken on the bus 
as $1.29962...*10^{-4}$

which is way off but I do not see where I am calculating wrong?

Comment: This is very hard to read.  The probability that all seats are empty is $.37^9=0.000129962$.   What makes you think this is way off?

Comment: On my Casio calculator I am using .equals the number above in the question

Comment: I don't understand.  Why do you believe that this numerical result is "way off"?

Comment: Its just the format it is written in why does your answer have 0.000129962 and mine is 1.29962...%10^-4% ?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I see what is happening but is there a way of multiplying my number to get your result 0.000129962?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  I assume your formula was meant to read $\binom 90 \times .63^0\times (1-.63)^{9-0}$ which would just be $.37^9$ which is correct.  I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: @Sean Please mark (nice) answers as accepted $\left( \color{limegreen}{\checkmark}\right)$. It would show that you appreciate effort and the contribution of the answerer. Please check all your other questions as well.

Comment: @callculus Will do in future I appreciate all the help people offer over the Stack community :)

Comment: @Sean That´s nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be computing
$$
\mathbb{P}[N=0] = \binom{9}{0} 0.63^0 (1-0.63)^9 = 0.37^9 \approx 0.00012996174
$$

Why do you think this is way off?

Comment: @ gt6989b: This is the answer I get when I plug $.37^9$ into a Casio Calculator = 1.299617....$10^{-4}$

Comment: @Sean that's correct, why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: Its just the format it is written in why does your answer have 0.000129962 and mine is 1.29962...%10^-4% ?

Comment: @Sean It means the same thing -- your calculator uses scientific notation, if you have $1.29 \times 10^{-4} = 0.000129$